# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does nothing when I stop

Tags: boot, freeze, 18.04, usb-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop (HP zbook studio g4). The problem I have at the moment is that it freezes when I do nothing for a while. When I leave the computer alone and then want to do something it does not respond anymore. This morning it was after about 30 seconds. What I mean with doing nothing is no input from me, but the computer was "busy" with installing packages or another time when the laptop was doing nothing.

Does anybody experience the same problems with the new Ubuntu? And does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

I have installed Ubuntu via the live usb and then started the installer. Then I also installed KDE to check if that works better, but it worked not better.

After this I also checked the live usb, but there also the laptop freezes. I am planning to download ubuntu again and try a reinstall. But I am not sure that this will solve the problem.

I assumed that 18.04 would work good, since there was already support since Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (but I had not installed that version before). 
http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00060684.pdf

Pepijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to set my video card in the BIOS to dedicated instead of auto.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing the same problem and I have keeping tab on your issue for a very long time for the answer myself. In the meantime, what I did was opening a *System Monitor* and keep it visible on my screen. This method so far will at least not freeze my screen randomly when I'm doing my work. Today, I found my laptop doesn't freeze anymore *(yet)* after I did these steps.

In UEFI (F10):

1. Under **Security** tab, change **Intel Software Guard Extensions (SGX)** to `Disable`,
2. Under **Advanced** tab, go to **Built-in Device Options** and change **Graphics** to `Discrete Graphics`.

Thanks to abaybektursun for [their answer on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392113). My solution was cut short after I did a few runs of trial and error myself prior to their answer. Please let me know if these methods work for you. Cheers!